# Drupal 7: Hiding labels with empty fields when viewing a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

How do I hide labels that have empty fields when viewing the actual node of a certain content type?

I'd really appreciate anyone's help, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could achieve this is by using a custom template file that would apply to all nodes of that content type.

Make sure that [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/7/source) exists in your `sites/all/themes/[mytheme]` directory first. This template must exist before other custom templates can be called.

Make a copy of your node.tpl.php and name it `node--[contenttype].tpl.php` (without the brackets).

If you have the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module enabled, you can throw a `dpm($content);` into the file to find out the name of the field you are trying to hide. Or you could look at the content type itself.

Once you have the name of the field, you can now insert this code before the `print render($content);` statement:

```
if (empty($content['my_field'])) {
  unset($content['my_field']);
}
```

Clear the cache, and your field will only appear if there is a value stored.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the labels of empty fields are hidden, maybe there's still a 'non breaking space' or some other leftover in the field?
You have to check the difference between an existing node where the problem occurs and a new node where you don't touch the particular field.

Set unwanted labels display hidden in nl/admin/structure/types/manage/selected_content_type/display

Comment: I'm looking at a label that appears when the field value is an empty string. Obviously this should be counted as empty, but for some reason it's not.

Comment: Can you inspect the element with firebug to see if it is really empty? Sometimes, a WYSIWYG adds an empty paragraph as text, so the field is not really empty.

Comment: The value is definitely an empty string. I've examined with firebug, as well as the devel tab on the node and the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to correct first answer. In node.tpl.php we should check #markup instead of field array:

```
if (empty($content['field_vac_req'][0]['#markup'])) {
  unset($content['field_vac_req']);
}
```

instead of

```
if (empty($content['my_field'])) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content type has a lot of fields looping this worked for me:

```
    foreach($content AS $key => $values) {
       if (!empty($content[$key][0]['#markup'])) {
          print render($content[$key]);
          }
    }
```